# How can I find the base URL in a Tapestry web app?

Tags: web-applications, tapestry

I'm trying to resuscitate a Tapestry webapp. I can serve it with `mvn jetty:run` but I don't know the base URL and available contexts. The developer is gone and I'm having problems finding out. I've tried to use the artifactID with no success. How can I find this out?

*jetty.xml* is not present. My *pom.xml*:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pt.edu.academiafa</groupId>
<artifactId>uavWeb</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>uavWeb Tapestry 5 Application</name>
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.M0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Too set up an application with a database, change the artifactId below to
         tapestry-hibernate, and add a dependency on your JDBC driver. You'll also
         need to add Hibernate configuration files, such as hibernate.cfg.xml. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
        <artifactId>tapestry-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- This adds automatic compression of JavaScript and CSS when in production mode. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
        <artifactId>tapestry-yuicompressor</artifactId>
        <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng-release-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>${easymock-release-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
        <artifactId>tapestry-test</artifactId>
        <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Provided by the servlet container, but sometimes referenced in the application
   code. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api-release-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Provide dependency to the Tapestry javadoc taglet which replaces the Maven component report -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
        <artifactId>tapestry-javadoc</artifactId>
        <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!--  Logger -->   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>   

   <!--  Ros dependencies -->  
   <dependency>
      <groupId>pt.edu.academiafa</groupId>
      <artifactId>seagull-rosjava-lib</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.2</version>
   </dependency> 

   <dependency>
    <groupId>pt.edu.academiafa.seagull</groupId>
    <artifactId>seagull_autopilot_msgs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.5</version>
   </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>pt.edu.academiafa.seagull</groupId>
        <artifactId>seagull_commons_msgs</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.dvdme</groupId>
      <artifactId>ForecastIOLib</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>uavWeb</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <tapestry.execution-mode>Qa</tapestry.execution-mode>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Run the application using "mvn jetty:run" -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Log to the console. -->
                <requestLog implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.NCSARequestLog">
                    <!-- This doesn't do anything for Jetty, but is a workaround for a Maven bug
                         that prevents the requestLog from being set. -->
                    <append>true</append>
                </requestLog>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>tapestry.execution-mode</name>
                        <value>development</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                <systemProperty>
                    <name>jetty.port</name>
                    <value>9090</value>
                </systemProperty>                        


                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting/>

<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>apache-staging</id>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/staging/</url>
    </repository>


    <repository>
          <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <id>RosJava</id>
          <name>Seagull RosJava</name>
          <url>http://bitbucket.org/ciafa-sw/maven2-release/raw/master/seagull-rosjava-libs</url>
          <layout>default</layout>      
    </repository>


    <repository>
          <id>RosMsgs</id>
          <name>Seagull Messages</name>
          <url>http://bitbucket.org/ciafa-sw/maven2-release/raw/master/ros-messages</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

    <repository>
          <id>RosMaster</id>
          <name>Seagull Master</name>
          <url>http://bitbucket.org/ciafa-sw/maven2-release/raw/master</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <tapestry-release-version>5.3.7</tapestry-release-version>
    <servlet-api-release-version>2.5</servlet-api-release-version>
    <testng-release-version>5.14.10</testng-release-version>
    <easymock-release-version>3.0</easymock-release-version>
    <slf4j-release-version>1.7.12</slf4j-release-version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Can you find anything in the pom.xml or jetty.xml if these are present?

Comment: I added the pom.xml to my question. I can't find anything useful. I've tried to create a new application for testing and it automatically sets the base URL (i.e. localhost:someport/baseURL) to be the artifactID. However, in this app, accessing /uavWeb gives a HTTP ERROR: 404 page, stating no access due to NOT_FOUND.

Comment: Hmm, so you are trying to access "http://localhost:9090/uavWeb/" ? Because that should be it I believe. Does the application have a Index page? Not sure what else can be the problem here.

Comment: It has an Index page, yes. That's what I thought too. I'm gonna try to see if any of the warnings is relevant to this problem.